# How could I convert my speech to text using twilio from my desktop?

Tags: api, twilio, speech-to-text

I am comparing the prformance of different Speech APIs just wanna know is there any way in twilio which would allow me to convert my speech to text simply from my desktop.
I used **speech recognition API** of **twilio** but **I guess it works when you make or recieve a call** or something like that. I want to use it like any other api in microsoft or ibm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio's speech recognition is not an API that you can initiate even via creating a call. 
Its only accessible as part of a TWIML(the Gather) , which you can send in **response** to Twilio's request for instructions.
So you cannot use it for your purpose or any other standalone speech to text system

Comment: So Can I use it for converting my speech to text ? if yes then how?

Comment: @AyushSharma - Twilio's speech recognition is not an API. You can use it to get text from incoming voice call but you cannot send your voice to get text. It can be used to write for example voice chat bot.

Comment: The speech to text used in `<Gather>` is actually powered by Google's [Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/), so if you just want an API, check that out.

Comment: Thanks everyone !